# How can I change the Apache Solr search URL?

Tags: 7, search

How can I change the default Apache Solr URL path from "search/apachesolr_search/term" to something else?

Comment: it's too bad that q0rban's post got voted up so many times, because it's not going to work - jhedstrom gives a thorough description of why simply overriding the path with hook_menu_alter will crash and burn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I've typically done this is to implement hook_menu_alter(). You can then customize the url in the exact way you choose:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu_alter().
 */
function example_menu_alter(&$menu) {
  // Ensure Apache Solr is the default and that the menu item exists.
  if (variable_get('apachesolr_search_make_default', 0) && isset($menu['search/apachesolr/%menu_tail'])) {
    $menu['search/%menu_tail'] = $menu['search/apachesolr/%menu_tail'];
    unset($menu['search/apachesolr/%menu_tail']);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This should work if you place it in settings.php:

```
function custom_url_rewrite_outbound(&$path, &$options, $original_path) {
  // Filter to get only the apache solr links with filters so it doesn't launch it for every link of our website
  if ($path == 'search/apachesolr_search/' && strpos($options['query'], 'filters') !== FALSE) {
    $new_path = $path.'?'.urldecode($options['query']);
    // See if we have a url_alias for our new path
    $sql = 'SELECT dst FROM {url_alias} WHERE src="%s"';
    $row = db_result(db_query($sql, $new_path));
    // If there is a dst url_alia, we change the path to it and erase the query
    if ($row) {
      $path = $row;
      $options['query'] = '';
    }
  }
}

function custom_url_rewrite_inbound(&$result, $path, $path_language) {
  // See if we have a url_alias for our new path
  $sql = 'SELECT src FROM {url_alias} WHERE dst="%s"';
  $row = db_result(db_query($sql, $path));
  if ($row) {
    // We found a source path
    $parts = preg_split('/[\?\&]/', $row);
    if (count($parts) > 1) {
      $result = array_shift($parts);
      // That's important because on my website, it doesn't work with the / at the end of result
      if ($result[strlen($result) - 1] == '/') {
        $result = substr($result, 0, strlen($result) - 1);
      }
      // Create the $_GET with the filter
      foreach ($parts as $part) {
        list($key, $value) = explode('=', $part);
        $_GET[$key] = $value;
        // Add this because the pager use the $_REQUEST variable to be set
        $_REQUEST[$key] = $value;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And then when you create a menu entry, you put the link to apache solr : search/apachesolr_search/?filters=tid:13

And create a url alias for search/apachesolr_search/?filters=tid:13 like products/tv.html

Found via: http://drupal.org/node/783836#comment-4136475

Comment: I have a feeling this is for D6. Is it easily adapted for D7, as the question asked?

Answer (score 4):

It is non-trivial to change the search path if you are only using the apachesolr search module. Since it depends on the core search module, the path is nearly hard-coded. It depends on search/{module}/%menu_tail. If you look at [search_view()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--search--search.pages.inc/function/search_view/6), the callback for the search module, you'll find that it calls [search_get_keys()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--search--search.module/function/search_get_keys/6), which expects the search keys to be in a particular part of the path. The apachesolr search module also uses this function to get keys, so implementing a simple hook_menu_alter() won't work on its own.

As mentioned in another answer here, if you are able to run Views 3.x, then your best bet is to use the [apachesolr views module](http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr_views). With this module, you can easily define any number of custom paths for search results.

If you can't run 3.x, then you'll need to use a combination of form alter (specifically, search_form) and custom menu callbacks to successfully change the default search path.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [solr views](http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr_views) for your site search.

1. Create a solr view.
2. Add a page display with the path you want
3. Add search text as a filter.
4. Exposed form in block
5. Put the block where you want your search box to go.

Comment: This does not work

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Adding custom search paths with hook_menu](http://evolvingweb.ca/story/apache-solr-mastery-how-add-custom-search-paths-hookmenu) by the guys at Evolving Web. It talks about how they wrote a custom module to create friendly URLs for their Solr searches. You'll probably need to tweak it a bit, but it's a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

What about creating a new menu callback like the following to make apachesolr return results at that path?

```
$menu['search']['page callback'] = 'apachesolr_search_view';
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can just modify a contributed module that does this: [Apache Solr Custom Path](http://drupal.org/project/custom_search_path).

Comment: This works only for D6

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change search/apachesolr_search/ to something else, for example 'inventory', you can try [Global redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/globalredirect) module.

The trick is to create 2 aliases - one for search/apachesolr_search/ (for faceted items) and another one without trailing slash (for the main search page). Global redirect might refuse to create 2 aliases for the same destination, but you can insert it into the db directly.