# How to change the search results URL?

Tags: 7, search, panels

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I change the apache solr search URL in Drupal?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1/how-can-i-change-the-apache-solr-search-url-in-drupal)

Is it possible to change the search result URL from /search/node/searchphrase to /search/searchphrase?

I'm using core search module and overriding the results page with Panels.

There's a discussion of the search results URL on [How can I change the Apache Solr search URL in Drupal?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1/how-can-i-change-the-apache-solr-search-url-in-drupal) but it seems to focus on Apache Solr.

Comment: The same solution applies